# IE 6.0 z-index issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, z-index

I am facing an issue with Z-index property of CSS in IE 6.0

HTML

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

CSS

```
#banner{
  background:url(pix/banner.PNG) top no-repeat;
  z-index = -1;
}
```

URL: http://www.whizlabs.com/examprep/

In IE 6.0, it shows a line on the forehead of girl, showing in the banner on the top of the page. In other browsers, line is not coming. How can i resolve this issue ?

Please help me.

Thanks
Devesh M

Comment: PS the "light" line on the girl also affects IE8 (and IE7 (at least in compatibility mode))

Comment: The technical explanation: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html

Answer (score 2):

There is really no reason to break the girl up into separate images.

Just use a single image and then position it relative to the top right of your wrapper

```
#banner{
    background:url(pix/girl.PNG) top no-repeat; /* where girl is the whole girl */
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:150px;
}
```

Then make sure that the  is just under your header div

Answer (score 1):

Z-index has no effect on statically positioned elements, therefore you would need to set the css `position` property to something else, like `relative`, but I don't think that you should use z-index in this case.

For a quick fix though you can try something like this:

```
   * html #banner { margin-top: -1px; }
```

This above trick only applies to MSIE6.

Answer (score 0):

Try puting the markup of the line before the markup of the girl, and place both using css. It usually worked for me in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

Also with Z-Index make sure to use numbers starting at 1.

If you are having trouble with an element, try giving it a Position property as well as give its parent a Position and a Z-Index.

Answer (score 0):

z-index only works on positioned elements.

Plus, you can only swap the depths of elements that are all contained by the same element - nested elements (one inside the other) cannot jump out of their nesting!